# Must people who live in Tel Aviv bring the Korban Pesach during Temple times?

Tags: passover, korban-pesach, pesach-sheni

Mishna Pessachim 9:1-2 says, based on Num. 9:10, that someone who is on a long journey may bring the Korban Pesach on the 14th of Iyar.

Rambam in Hilchot Korban Pessach 5:8 rules that the distance of a long jorney is 15 mil from the walls of Jerusalem, which is about 15 km. There in Halacha 2 he also rules that someone who is at that distance and does not bring the Korban Pesach is obligated to bring it on the 14th of Iyar, but is not punished by karet if he willingly ignores this opportunity (He does not say what happens if someone is both times on a long journey).

If the Temple stood today, would people from Tel Aviv have to bring the Korban Pesach? Or is this distance considered "דרך רחוקה"?

Comment: Tel Aviv is clearly more than 15km from Jerusalem. What's your question?

Comment: @DoubleAA I cannot imagine that only people from the vicinity of Jerusalem are obligated to bring the Pessach and to eat it since it is so significant.

Comment: Are you asking if nowadays we would count distance by time rather than kilometers?, i.e., the time it used to take to walk 15 mil?

Comment: You have an obligation to go to the Temple from all of Israel.

Comment: @N.T.: Source? From outside Israel there is no obligation? For every regel seemingly there is a chiyuv to go...

Comment: @N.T. that only applies to capable males, and also can be fulfilled on the later days of the holiday